# Spark Driver Memory Configuration

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, apache-spark-sql

I am getting the following error in my Spark application:-

```
Container [pid=7115,containerID=container_1516699670283_0001_02_000001] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.4 GB of 1.4 GB physical memory used; 3.4 GB of 6.9 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

I am currently using `m3.2x large EC2` instance (https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) as my driver resource.

I have a couple of questions here:

1) If I don't specify `spark.driver.memory`, is there any default value that is used?

2) In this case, what memory of the driver should I specify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The default value of spark.driver.memory is 1g.
(See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

2) You need to specify spark.driver.memory, spark.driver.cores, spark.driver.maxResultSize (read about this parameters folowing the link https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)